# 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403, httpforbiddenhandler

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the main server and I can only access the files through cPanel.
This is the email I received from my hosting company. If you can help me, please help me

this email in being sent to inform you that your site   has been identified as a source of spam (unsolicated commercial email)being sent from your server.

to prevent this from causing futher issues ,we have disabled the domain in question by limiting its permissions.you may re-enable this domain,but that failure to rectify this issue may result in permanent disablement of the site in question.

if you're unaware of any spam being sent from under this domain , this can postentially indicate asecurity breach of your site .if this is the case,you may want to take look into our dreamshield service ,which helps keep your site clean and healthy.

you can read more about the dreamshield service on the following help page:

if you have any further questions,please let us know

I disabled plugins
I deleted the .htaccess file
I manipulated the access of files and folders

Comment: Not sure what their dreamshield service does, but if I were you I would use this service.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to Dream Shield at the moment

Comment: You do have access to it. Just send an email to the support team.

Comment: Nobody here can help you since the problem is somewhere in your theme or plugin files. And nobody can view any of these.

Comment: One of my friends bought this domain and host for me and I can't contact her at the moment

Comment: I have access to the original files through FileZilla, but I don't know what to do to fix the problem

Comment: I am new and do not have much experience

Comment: As said: nobody can help you without having a look at the files. The site might be compromised. In that case what you can do (apart from hireing someone that has knowledge) is to update all plugins, then check the plugins folder via cPanel for plugins that are not part of the install. Sometimes there are backdoors that look like genuine plugins, but are actually maliscious.

Comment: I disabled all plugins but the problem still persists

Comment: I advised you to check the plugins folder. Are there any folders in it that do not belong to an existing plugin in the wordpress backend? You might encounter a folder such as "wp-backups", which is not a wordpress plugin, but can contain files that cause your problem.

Comment: Is it possible to scan the entire file via FTP to find a problem?

Comment: No. That’s not possible.

Comment: In my opinion, best you can do is: 1. backup the files and database. 2. Deactivate and then delete all plugins via the Wordpress backend. 3. Check the plugins folder for any remaining folders.

Comment: If there are still files in the plugins directory, these might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Delete those and reinstall all plugins via the Wordpress backend.

Comment: My dear friend supported all the files and deleted all the files, how can I reinstall WordPress and all previous posts and settings remain?

Comment: Is there any visual training I want to go through?

Comment: Most of the files have been deleted and now the error is 404.

Comment: This link tells uou how to reinstall wordpress:

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/before-install/howto-install/

Comment: Would you like to tell me how to return the pages and posts I posted?

Comment: Which pages and posts are in which root or FTP folder?

Comment: They are in the database. You cannot access them via ftp.

Comment: You should link the existing database to your wordpress install.

Comment: This you do in the `wp-config.php` file.